# How would I use NSUserDefaults to save the state of a button?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

Essentially what I'd like to do is save the selection the user makes (topbutton or bottombutton) so that when the user exists the app, and returns, their choice vote is saved and they do not have to redo it.

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    var nicebutton = sender as! UIButton

    nicebutton.enabled = false

    var nopebutton = nicebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(102) as! UIButton

    nopebutton.enabled = true



    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)



    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.save()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}



@IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var nopebutton = sender as! UIButton

    nopebutton.enabled = false

    var nicebutton = nopebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(101) as! UIButton

    nicebutton.enabled = true
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
    object.save()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add code below and set your button state,

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "niceButtonEnabled");
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

anf of course you need to get before showing the buttons.

```
if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("niceButtonEnabled")){
   //enable the button which you selected before
}
```

hope it helps.

More detailed version..

```
  @IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {

   var nopebutton = sender as! UIButton

   if let nopeE =    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("nopeButtonEnabled") {
    //enable the button which you selected before
       nopebutton.enabled = nopeE
   }else{
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "nopeButtonEnabled");
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
   }

   var nicebutton = nopebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(101) as! UIButton
   if let niceE =    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("niceButtonEnabled") {
       //enable the button which you selected before
        nicebutton.enabled = niceE
   }else{
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "niceButtonEnabled");
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
   }
   let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
   let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
   let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
   object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
   object.save()
   self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation:    UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
  }
```

Comment: also remember to add `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` if you need it saved right away, otherwise system decides when it gets actually saved

Comment: so then I would essentially put the first line below the nicebutton variable and have the nicebutton.enabled = false inbetween the if statement?

Comment: @JamesChen I added more detailed version for you for bottomBottom and you can do the same for the other buttons too.